# Adding fields from a sharepoint list to a word 2007 document

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-word

I am working on sharepoint foundation 2010. I have to add some fields  from a list to word 2007 document (automatically of course every time an item is added to the list)( the document contains a paragraph and I have to complete this paragraph from the list fields).. I've searched your site for help and I found an answer that seemed ambiguous to me:

> If you create a document library with custom fields (or better yet a content type), Office 2007 documents will include the fields as properties of the document. Word inludes features to add those fields to the document (Insert->QuickParts-Document Property).
>   You can automate the placement of items on the document by adding a document template to your content type.

Can someone Please give me more details about that method or if exists a better solution.

Comment: i also found another method using sharepoint designer workflow but i am not well experimented in manipulating such complex procedures. So anyone can help me with an answer ??

Comment: I tried the full procedure concerning document generation using a sharepoint designer workflow but i was unceccessful  it is detailed right here: http://www.quercussolutions.com/blog/index.php/out-of-the-box-document-generation-in-sharepoint-2/

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit unclear what are exact requirements.

Using steps provided in quote you can add custom fields to the document - i.e. you need to add some columns to the library and then insert custom fields into document/template. Then if you create new document it will contain information from custom fields. (Something similar like it is described [here](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/simple-sharepoint-invoicing-part-1).

If you have some list and you need do create document in the library with information from the list item you will not be able to achieve it with OOTB SharePoint. You can try to use some third party tool like our product [Documents Generator](http://www.sharepointdrive.com) (free version should be enough)